# Response with headers swagger-ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using [Swagger-ui version 2.1.4](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), i have hosted it locally and provided it my own Json file and API it opens the document fine but i want to add headers in the Response Messages but i did not get how to do it, i followed the [swagger specification](http://swagger.io/specification/#headersObject) to do it, but unfortunately i am still unsuccessful.
My sample code is here.

```
 "responses" : {
           "200" : {
              "description" : "SUCCESSFULLY_RETRIVED",
              "schema" : {
                 "$ref" : "#/definitions/Object"
              }
           },
           "500" : {
               "description" : "UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR",
               "headers": {
               "X-Rate-Limit-Limit": {
               "description": "The number of allowed requests in the current period",
               "type": "integer"
               }                    
           }

        },
        "deprecated" : false
     }
```

Comment: Try importing your swagger.json file here:  http://editor.swagger.io

Comment: Does the API you are calling actually return the X-Rate-Limit-Limit Header? You could try using the Chrome Advance Rest Client to send a sample request and note the response has or has not got the header: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client-appl/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC&utm_medium=InsideApplication&utm_campaign=About

Comment: Can you please tell the exact error that you are getting here? I may be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

Quite late for a reply but I chanced upon this while looking for an example of a similar requirement. Your stuff should work, not sure why it doesn't work for you. If you provided the exact error, that would have helped.

The following yaml works fine for me and yours should work fine also.

```
    500:
      description: Customer creation error
      headers:
        Error-Id:
          description: the relevant 500 Error
          type: string
```